# how to wait for all AJAX to continue Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a Chrome Extension which I'm finally getting around to updating [been over 6mo].
I went through the process of upgrading the Manifest version from 1 to 2.

My extension adds a "Poke all" button to Facebook so you do not have to individually poke every person.

The problem is, they moved their pokes to facebook.com/pokes, instead of in a frame on the homepage.

So my workaround was to tell people to reload the page once they were on /pokes, that way the script would reload, and inject the "Poke All" button.  Now, I want to fix this so that when the user goes to facebook.com, and then clicks "Pokes," and the pokes load, the button automatically appears.   I had set it up with a setTimeout for 1.5 seconds, but if anyone has a slow connection, 1.5 seconds is not enough, and the script tries to inject the button too early, resulting in no button.

So basically, I add an event listener to the "Pokes" link.  That's what I was adding a timeout to run `show_pokes()`, which runs the injection code.

My idea was to put a `$(document).ready()` **inside** `show_pokes()`, but that didn't work because it never continued in the function.  I guess `$(document).ready()` is only for the initial page loading?  So then I tried

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){ /*huge chunk of code here*/ })
```

but that also just hung, and never finished the function.

So I'm pretty sure Facebook uses AJAX requests when you click on a facebook tab [Please see [here](http://imageshack.us/a/img443/6369/87426057.png)], so perhaps if I can set up an event to wait till AJAX finishes, and then it can continue in my function, and inject the button?  Any help would be appreciated, or if you need more code, or more specifics, let me know.   Or if you could go to Facebook and see how it loads those tabs, [and confirm or deny whether it uses AJAX] that would be a great help too.

Comment: One common way to solve this is via referencing counting. You set up a counter, lets called it `ajaxCounter`.  For every request you start, increment the counter.  For every request received, decrement the counter.  When the counter reaches `0` again, you've received all your requests.

To be really fancy, for every request you start, you create an array entry.  When the request is received you remove it from the array.  In theory, this allows you to retry failed requests.

Comment: hello, the problem is, it's Facebook's ajax code.  and I do not have control over it.  I am just running a script on top of it, and want to know when it finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy stated increment a counter. Be careful that during this loop on AJAX return `i` will have moved on. If you need to retain the current `i` then you'll want to put the AJAX call inside a closure.

```
var pokes = $(".pokeMe");
var poked = 0;
var failed = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < pokes.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url, 
        success : function(data) {
            poked++;

            if (poked + failed == pokes.length) {
                // all actions returned
            }
        },
        error : function(data) {
            failed++;

            // optional logic
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, you misunderstood. :S sorry if I wasn't clear.  I already have all of my Poke code done.  The problem is the trigger.  I want it to load after the user clicks on the pokes tab.  I added an event listener to execute the function to *print* the button. [clicking does the poke] What I want is to be able to have the function called by the event listener, and then when it's called, wait until it loads the "Pokes" page.  I say "wait for ajax" because I think FB uses ajax to load the pokes page.  Follow what I'm saying at all?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Well that's considerably more difficult. This will take a bit of sleuthing. But if you notice on the poke button it has an 'ajaxify' URL there. Possibly, you're script could alter poke links so they route through a function of your design allowing your code to initiate the AJAX request. Thereby allowing you to handle it's completion. Now, it is entirely possible that such an action is a complete violation of FB TOS as you are altering the way their website works so tread carefully.

Comment: yeah, I would prefer to let fb handle its own code and just work around it.. but anyway for now I have just put in a setTimeout for 1.8 seconds.  That's long enough for most connections to load it.  And if not they can reload the page and it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help you at all, but it sounds like you could use the `$.when().done()` that jQuery provides. That way it will wait until all the AJAX calls inside of the `when()` are done and then move forward with the rest of the function that you would call inside the `done()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/